# scanner records string with spaces and numbers?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I'm taking user input via a scanner that needs to record something like "Gallon 2% milk." 
Right now I have

```
    System.out.print("Enter product description: ");
    String description = in.next();
```

now this works fine for things like "milk" but when I enter "gallon 2% milk" it returns an error.

also, I've tried using

```
    String description = in.nextLine();
```

but that prints "Enter product description: Enter product quantity:"

I'm assuming that is because the next line in my code is

```
    System.out.print("Enter product quantity: ");
```

thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: what have you got before `System.out.print("Enter product description: ");`  If you are pressing the ENTER key before this then that keystroke will also need to be consumed used `nextLine`

Comment: Please confirm that `Enter product quantity:` is being printed before you have entered the product description?

Comment: idk how to like this but this was the culprit! thank you @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if have a prompt before `System.out.print("Enter product description: ");` and you are pressing the ENTER key before this then that keystroke will also need to be consumed used nextLine.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using `in.nextLine()` for taking in strings including spaces and the enter key press. The reason you are getting both outputs on a single line is because you are using the `System.out.print(String)` method. That doesn't add a new line to the output stream so subsequent calls to it append to the same line. Use `System.out.println(String)` instead.